# FastText: Can't see the representation of words that starts with @ or @

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I am working in an NLP project using FastText. I have some texts which contains words like @.poisonjamak, @aminagabread, @*iamquak123* and I want to see their FastText representation. I want to mention that the model has the following form:

```
# FastText
ft_model = FastText(word_tokenized_corpus,
                    max_n=0,
                    vector_size=64,
                    window=5,
                    min_count=1,
                    sg=1,
                    workers=20,
                    epochs=50,
                    seed=42)
```

Using this I can see their representation, however I have an error

```
print(ft_model.wv['@.poisonjamak'])

KeyError: 'cannot calculate vector for OOV word without ngrams'
```

Of course, these words are in my texts. I have the above error in all these 3 words, however if I do the following this is working.

```
print(ft_model.wv['@.poisonjamak']) -----> print(ft_model.wv['poisonjamak'])
print(ft_model.wv['@aminagabread']) -----> print(ft_model.wv['aminagabread'])
print(ft_model.wv['@_iamquak123_']) -----> print(ft_model.wv['_iamquak123_'])
```

**Question: So do you know why I have this problem?**

**Update:**
My dataset called 'df' and the column with texts called 'text'. I using the following code to prepare the texts for the fast text. The FastText is trained on word_tokenized_corpus

```
extra_list = df.text.tolist()
final_corpus = [sentence for sentence in extra_list if sentence.strip() !='']

word_punctuation_tokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
word_tokenized_corpus = [word_punctuation_tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in final_corpus]
```

Comment: It seems related to tokenization, even if I can't find the right reference in source code...

Comment: @Stefano Fiorucci - anakin87 thank you so much for your help! Actually I am using nltk tokinzer, so probably this is the problem. Check the update on my code

Comment: As you can see here (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nltk-tokenize-wordpuncttokenizer/), `WordPunctTokenizer` is probably involved in your issue. In fact, if you apply this tokenizer to `"@aminagabread"`, the output is `['@', 'aminagabread']`

Comment: @Stefano Fiorucci - anakin87 Thanks a lot. I got it, I will use just this simple tokenizer 'text here'.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments note, the main issue is likely with your tokenizer, which won't put `'@'` characters inside your tokens. As a result, your `FastText` model isn't seeing the tokens you expect – but probably *does* have a word-vector for the 'word' `'@'`.

Separately reviewing your actual `word_tokenized_corpus`, to see what it truly includes before the mdoel gets to do its training, is a good way to confirm this (or catch this class of error in the future).

There is however another contributing issue: your use of the `max_n=0` parameter. This essentially *turns off* subword learning, by qualifying *no* positive-length word-substrings (aka 'character n-grams') for vector-learning. This setting essentially turns `FastText` into plain `Word2Vec`.

If instead you were using `FastText` in a more usual way, it would've learned subword-vectors for some of the subwords in `'aminagabread'` etc, and thus would'vbe provided synthetic "guess" word-vectors for the full `'@aminagabread'` unseen OOV token.

So in a way, you're *only* seeing the error letting you know about a problem in your tokenization because of this other deviation from usual `FastText` OOV behavior. If you really want `FastText` for its unique benefit of synthetic vectors for OOV words, you should return to a more typical `max_n` setting.

Separate usage tips:

- `min_count=1` is usually a bad idea with such word2vec-family algorithms, as such rare words don't have enough varied usage examples to get good vectors themselves, but the failed attempt to try degrades training for surrounding words. Often, discarding such words (as with the default `min_count=5` as if they weren't there at all improves downstream evaluations.
- Because of some inherent threading inefficiencies of the Python Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL"), and the Gensim approach to iterating over your corpus in one thread, parcelling work out to worker threads, it is likely you'll get higher training throughput with *fewer* workers than your `workers=20` setting, even if you have 20 (or far more) CPU cores. The exact best setting in any situation will vary by a lot of things, including some of the model parameters, and only trial-and-error can narrow the best values. But it's more likely to be in the 6-12 range, even when more cores are available, than 16+.